# Html5 Barcode scan webapp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to scan barcode via webcam, I searched a lot but i didn't get anything. I need pure Html 5, Java script,jquery web app. Anyone knows, Please guide me. I spend so much time but i didn't get. Please anyone help me!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried [QuaggaJS](https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/)?

Comment: QuaggaJS is a really good framework to use. It doesn't support QrCode but supports widely recognised barcode formats.

Comment: By reading the documentation linked. If you get stuck, post another question with the code that doesn't work for you.